# iOS - parse xml DATASET

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, dataset, nsxmlparser

My Xml data that i want to parse

```
<DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/“>

<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-     microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns=“">

<Products diffgr:id="Products1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<ItemCode>001G1-R25111-1701</ItemCode>
<ItemName>Autocad 2015</ItemName>
<Price>160714.000000</Price>
</Products>
<Products diffgr:id="Products2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<ItemCode>011-0656</ItemCode>
<ItemName>"SVC, HARDWARE TEST 1"</ItemName>
<Price>0.000000</Price>
</Products>
<Products diffgr:id="Products3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<ItemCode>011-0657</ItemCode>
<ItemName>"SVC, HARDWARE TEST 2"</ItemName>
<Price>0.000000</Price>
</Products>

</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>

This is my view.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface view : NSObject
{
int *itemcode;
NSString *itemname;
NSString *price;
}


@property (nonatomic, assign) int *itemcode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *itemname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *price;
@end

view.m

#import "view.h"

@implementation view
@synthesize itemcode,itemname,price;

@end
```

Below is the code im using to parse data:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"DataTable"])
{
    if(!soapResults)
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    recordResults = TRUE;
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) {

    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]) {

    aMessage = [[view alloc] init];
}
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
if( recordResults )
    [soapResults appendString: string];

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString       *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]) {

    [messages addObject:aMessage];

    [aMessage setValue: soapResults forKey:elementName];
    NSLog(@"MESSAGES COUNT: %d",messages.count);
    NSLog(@"MESSAGE: %@",aMessage);

    aMessage = nil;
}
// as this is the last element
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"])
{
    recordResults = FALSE;
}
}
```

Im not getting the parsed data and it is crashing in didendelement. 
    'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ItemCode.'

Answer (score 0):

In the view.h file u should declare variables as

```
 int * ItemCode;
 NSString * ItemName;
 NSString * Price;
```

the variables should be equal to the tag names